# How to select a value from a drop down using protractor?

Tags: javascript, html, protractor

I'm trying to click on a button and then select a value from the drop down. I'm clicking on the City button and then choosing Toronto. however i'm not even able to click on the button.

Here is the html :

I have tried using by.className : 
element(by.className("filter-button")).click();

Using by. xpath: 
element(by. xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]")).click();

Doesn't seem to work.

```
<div class="content-wrapper list-page">
    <div class="content">
        <div class="section-wrapper page-full-width">
            <div class="section page-centered">
                <div class="filter-bar"><span class="medium-utility-label filter-by-label">Filter by:</span>
                    <div role="button" class="filter-button-wrapper" tabindex="0" aria-label="Filter by City: All" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                        <div class="filter-button">City
                            <svg class="filter-button-caret icon icon-caret-down" width="16px" height="16px" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                                <path d="M7.6741598,11.3413318 L8.03952616,11.7324251 L8.40489252,11.3413318 L14.8653664,4.42595055 L14.1346336,3.74328687 L7.6741598,10.6586682 L8.40489252,10.6586682 L1.86536636,3.65866816 L1.13463364,4.34133184 L7.6741598,11.3413318 Z M7.6741598,11.3413318" fill="#979797"></path>
                            </svg>
                        </div>
                        <div class="filter-popup">
                            <ul>
                                <li>
                                    <a class="category-link selected" href="?" rel="nofollow">
                                        <svg class="selected-filter-checkmark icon icon-checkmark" width="16px" height="16px" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                                            <path d="M6.2,14.4L0,8.2l2.5-2.5l3.5,3.5c0.1,0.1,0.2,0.1,0.2,0L13.5,2L16,4.5L6.2,14.4z"></path>
                                        </svg>All</a>
                                </li>
                                <li><a class="category-link" href="?location=Chicago%2C%20Illinois" rel="nofollow">Chicago, Illinois</a>
                                </li>
                                <li><a class="category-link" href="?location=Edmonton%2C%20Alberta%2C%20Canada" rel="nofollow">Edmonton, Alberta, Canada</a>
                                </li>
```

Answer (score 0):

You'd need to first click the dropdown, then locate the option you want and click that.
Try the following:

```js
const EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
const city = element.all(by.css('.filter-bar .filter-button-wrapper .filter-button')).get(0);
const dropDownPopUp = element.all(by.css('.filter-popup')).get(0);
const toronto = dropDownPopUp.all(by.cssContainingText('.category-link', 'Toronto, Ontario, Canada'));

const selectToronto = function () {
 return browser.wait(EC.elementToBeClickable(city))
  .then(function() {
   return city.click();
  })
  .then(function() {
   return browser.wait(EC.elementToBeClickable(toronto))
  })
  .then(function() {
   return toronto.click();
  });
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I'm Not getting an error anymore when i try to click on the button but it seems like it's finding more than once instance :                                                                   
[16:09:08] W/element - more than one element found for locator By(css selector, .filter-bar .filter-button-wrapper .filter-button) - the first result will be used

Comment: If there's more than one element, and, in this case, you need the first one, you can go like this:  
`element.all(by.css('.filter-bar .filter-button-wrapper .filter-button')).first();`  
Were you able to select the right option from the dropdown with my method? Consider marking my answer as correct for others to see. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks Joaquin. I'm not getting the warning anymore but nothing is happening in the GUI. Clicking on the button doesn't open the pop up drop down

Answer (score 0):

get the dropdown element, then get the options and cycle through them looking for the one you want

```
async function selectFromList(dropDownElem,stringValue){
    const dropDownOptions = await dropDownElem.all(by.tagName('li'));
    for(let i =0;i< dropDownOptions.length;i++){
        if(await dropDownOptions[i].getText() === stringValue){
            await dropDownOptions[i].click();
        }
    }
}
const dropDownElem = element(by.className("filter-popup");
selectFromList(dropDownElem, "Chicago, Illinois");
```

I havent actually run this so you might need to tweak it

Comment: might wanna add a break in there for the loop too